# Connection Monitoring between Arduino and Webserver

Tags: php, mysql, http, post, arduino

**What I want to do:**

To monitor the connection in between an Arduino and a Apache webserver and show "Online" or "Offline" with the last online time on the web browser.

**How I do it:**

My Arduino is sending a heartbeat to *heartbeat.php* by using HTTP POST. In the beginning of the *heartbeat.php*, I set a session variable and store the current timestamp to the MySQL database and then redirect to *index.php*.

*heartbeat.php*

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['hb'] = 1;
    include("connect.php");
    $link=connection();
    $sql="UPDATE heartbeat SET time=NOW() WHERE 1";
    mysql_query($sql,$link);
    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

A javascript in *index.php* will perform auto refresh and load *healthcheck.php* into the HTML Body content.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
            $("#content").load("healthcheck.php");
        }, 1000);
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    });
</script>
```

In the *healthcheck.php*, the script will check for the session variable to determine whether the system is online. If the system is offline then it will query for the last online time and display on the browser.

*healthcheck.php*

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connect.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['hb']))
{
    echo '<h1>System Online!!!</h1>';
    unset($_SESSION['hb']);
}
else
{
    echo '<h1>System Offline!!!</h1>';
    $link=connection();
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM heartbeat", $link);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        printf("Last Online: %s", $row["time"]);
    }       
}
?>
```

**Problems:**

when I browse *localhost/heartbeat.php* using my pc's browser, I can see "Online" before it turns "Offline" with the last online time displays, this is what I want to achieve by using Arduino.

However when I test the scripts with Arduino, it always display "Offline" and the last online time is getting updated according to my refresh interval.

I think this is because of the session variable is set in the arduino itself so my pc's browser didn't get it hence always display "Offline", please correct me if I'm wrong.

I am looking for advises and suggestions to achieve this online monitoring function in an effective way, any suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think session variables are there to store data on a per-client basis, so the session variable you set in the session from arduino to server is different from the session variable in the session from pc webbrowser to server.

Comment: well, why don't you just make a program that sends ICMP/Ping to the arduino host, and when it does not answer, identify it as "offline"? It would be less trouble, and avoid you to add another responsibility in your Arduino.

Comment: @til_b yes you're right. I got the concept of session variables wrong previously and hence I got stuck and lost.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you consider being your "session id", but I think you're using it more like an API key to identify your device towards the web service. Session ids are usually tokens put into cookies in `HTTP` requests, and are a pain to manage and track, and you don't need them for your use case. Just `POST` the token, and get it through the `$_POST` variable!

And as I suggested in a comment, why don't you just make a program that sends `ICMP`/`Ping` to the Arduino, and when it does not answer, identify it as "offline"?

It would be less trouble, and avoid you to add another responsibility in your Arduino.

Comment: Ping the arduino would be a solution but what I worry is my server is listening to another signal which can happen anytime, so it has to be standby all the time. will the traffic/connection be affected when the signal is coming in while my server is ping-ing the arduino, furthermore i have to monitor not only 1 arduino

Comment: I really did not understand your comment, I'm sorry... it looks like you google translated twice?!

Comment: no i didn't use google translate. in short my server will be connected to multiple arduino clients. each of them might send a triggering signal anytime, so i suspect the network traffic will be affected if i ask the server to ping every arduino client. do you get me??

Comment: I was being sarcastic, but I still did not understand what you're talking about... You say "what I worry is my server is listening to another signal", what are you talking about exactly? And what "has to be standby all the time"? and what do you mean by "will the traffic/connection be affected when the signal is coming in while my server is ping-ing the arduino"? I'm missing big clues, and the way you say it is... weird :-)

Comment: well, you don't need to ping every second, you can just use a PHP package that enables you to send/receive one ping message, and do it every minute or so, and if the host does not respond, send 5 pings and if all fail mark it as offline

Comment: I'm sorry for didn't structure my sentences properly.
I have a pc as a server, and many arduino with sensors as clients. 
The arduino will send a data packet to the server immediately when the sensors' value reaches the threshold. And I need to determine the arduino is online or offline in few seconds(hence I'm thinking to detect a heartbeat signal from arduino every second). 
I am worrying that the server might fail to receive the sensor triggering signal if the server needs to ping all the arduino every second. 
Sorry for my ignorance, I really have no clues about networking.